# Creating a 2 dimensional array with loops

Tags: java, arrays

I'm asking this question because I need to create a two dimensional array as the program is running. All the other questions on the website have data already inside the array, which is what I don't have so I can't follow those tutorials.

Prior to this code snippet, I've got all the variables initialized properly.

Excuse my formatting, this is the first question I've asked on here

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfVals; i++){
    numSpc = 50 - values[i];
    for (int k = 0; k < 51; k++){
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i]; j++){
            twoDim[k[j]]=1;
        }
        for (int m = 0; m < numSpc; m ++){
            twoDim[k[j]]=0;
        }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do here is make an array inside twoDim called k, and then edit the values in there. It want it to look like `twoDim[[0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1], [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1]];` except there would be 50 values in each internal array (k).

The problem is, I keep getting two different kinds of errors. One is saying it can't find the variable j (`cannot find symbol`) and the other error says `array required, but int found` about k. How can I fix this?

Comment: 1. `j`'s scope is limited only to its `for-loop`. 2. How have you defined `twoDim`?

Comment: `twoDim` was defined with `int twoDim[] = new int[numOfVals];`. `numOfVals` is just an integer user input. I'll fix the scoping, thank you for point out that j is outside of it's loop in the second mention of it. I think i copy-pasted but forgot to change it to `k[m]` instead of `k[j]`

Answer (score 0):

The issues are :

1. `j`'s scope is limited only to its `for-loop`. You can't access it outside the loop.
2. `twoDim[k[j]]=1;` and `twoDim[k[j]]=0`. k is of type `int`, you can't try to use it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < numOfVals; i++){
        numSpc = 50 - values[i];
        for (int k = 0; k < 51; k++){
            twoDim[k]=[];
            for (int j = 0; j < values[i]; j++){
                twoDim[k].push(1);
            }
            for (int m = 0; m < numSpc; m ++){
                twoDim[k].push(0);
            }
        }
    }
```